# How can I configure cabal to use different folders for 32-bit and 64-bit packages?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm doing some testing of 64-bit GHC on Windows, in tandem with migrating code forward to GHC 7.6.1. This means that I have both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of GHC 7.6.1 installed, so I can distinguish 64-bit specific problems from general problems with 7.6.1.

My cabal config file (`$APPDATA/cabal/config`) contains

```
libsubdir: $pkgid\$compiler
```

which means that both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of packages I install are ending up in e.g. zip-archive-0.1.1.8/ghc-7.6.1, and overwriting each other.

Is there any variable like `$compiler` but distinguishing 32 and 64 bit, or other technique I can use to get it to keep the packages apart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$arch` (and/or `$os`) with [recent enough Cabal versions](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/commit/5c2082d210e1c8f796e89c4f0382fb46fb500115), which will be replaced by a string such as `x86_64` (see Cabal documentation section ["Path variables in the simple build system"](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#path-variables-in-the-simple-build-system) for more details)

Comment: Thanks! I tried quite a few things before asking the question, including guessing at variables, searching through the docs and reading the Cabal source, so I don't know how I missed this.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the Right Way to do it, but on my laptop where I boot into 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems I have a hack set up to deal with this. Basically, I have two directories, .cabal-i386 and .cabal-x86_64, and I switch back and forth via symlinks. In my .zshrc:

```
CabalDir=$HOME/.cabal-`uname -m`
if [ ! -d $CabalDir]; then
    echo WARNING: no cabal directory yet for `uname -m`, creating one.
    mkdir -p $CabalDir/{bin,lib,logs,share}
fi
ln -sft $HOME/.cabal $CabalDir/{bin,lib,logs,share}
```

Perhaps you can adopt some similar strategy, giving yourself a short command to switch out some symlinks (or whatever Windows' analog of symlinks is).

Comment: I'd considered something like this, but I typically want to have multiple console windows open each pointing to a different ghc (which I do by manipulating the PATH) and work on them in parallel.