# Why do cabal sandboxes not have separate bin directories for different architectures?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I've been working with multiple versions of `ghc` as well as targeting multiple architectures (`x86_64` and `ia32` for now) all being built on the same `x86` machine.

So I followed the "using 32 GHC on 64 bit" instructions at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Compiling32on64 a while back, but didn't think to isolate my sandboxes. So naturally I wound up with some weird linking errors after extending my cabal package in a way that required some of the executables in the `.cabal-sandbox/bin` directory (still not totally sure what I changed, but at one point I was able to build two different architectures using the same sandbox). My current solution is basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12394249/1542000

So what considerations go into handling multiple architectures in the cabal build system? I see that packages in a sandbox are separated by architecture, but why wasn't separating the `bin` directory by architecture a simple extension of package separation?

Comment: Honest question: why are you using my crappy hack solution instead of the accepted solution on the linked question?

Comment: Because I hacked it up on my own a couple days ago, and then while writing this question I found your post and was like "hey that's basically what I did!"

Comment: And what goes wrong when you use the correct solution...?

Comment: Haven't tried with $arch yet. Will try that now. So it's all just a configuration issue of pointing to the right bin directory? I wasn't sure if there was something deeper to the problem of supporting multiple architectures / why the cabal developers handled package separation but didn't also add $arch at the same time (or did they?)

Comment: Okay, I don't know the answer to the "why" question. I agree it is annoying, though.